# What (tf) are the secrets behind PDF memory allocation (CGPDFDocumentRef)

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, memory

For a PDF reader I want to prepare a document by taking 'screenshots' of each page and save them to disc. First approach is

```
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) someURL);
for (int i = 1; i<=pageCount; i++) 
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];      
  CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i);
  ...//getting + manipulating graphics context etc.
  ...
  CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
  ...
  UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  ...//saving the image to disc 
  [pool drain];
}
CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
```

This results in a lot of memory which seems not to be released after the first run of the loop (preparing the 1st document), but no more unreleased memory in additional runs:

```
MEMORY BEFORE:          6 MB
MEMORY DURING 1ST DOC: 40 MB
MEMORY AFTER 1ST  DOC: 25 MB 
MEMORY DURING 2ND DOC: 40 MB
MEMORY AFTER 2ND  DOC: 25 MB
....
```

Changing the code to

```
for (int i = 1; i<=pageCount; i++) 
{
  CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) someURL);
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];      
  CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i);
  ...//getting + manipulating graphics context etc.
  ...
  CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
  ...
  UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  ...//saving the image to disc 
  CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
  [pool drain];
}
```

changes the memory usage to

```
MEMORY BEFORE:          6 MB
MEMORY DURING 1ST DOC:  9 MB
MEMORY AFTER 1ST  DOC:  7 MB 
MEMORY DURING 2ND DOC:  9 MB
MEMORY AFTER 2ND  DOC:  7 MB
....
```

but is obviously a step backwards in performance.

When I start reading a PDF (later in time, different thread) in the first case no more memory is allocated (staying at 25 MB), while in the second case memory goes up to 20 MB (from 7).

In both cases, when I remove the `CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);` line memory is (nearly) constant at 6 MB during and after all preparations of documents.

Can anybody explain whats going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGPDFDocument caches pretty aggressively and you have very little control over that, apart from - as you've done - releasing the document and reloading it from disk.

The reason you don't see a lot of allocations when you remove the CGContextDrawPDFPage call is that Quartz loads page resources lazily. When you just call CGPDFDocumentGetPage, all that happens is that it loads some basic metadata, like bounding boxes and annotations (very small in memory).

Fonts, images, etc. are only loaded when you actually draw the page - but then they're retained for a relatively long time in an internal cache. This is meant to make rendering faster, because page resources are often shared between multiple pages. Also, it's fairly common to render a page multiple times (e.g. when zooming in). You'll notice that it's significantly faster to render a page the second time.

Comment: Thank you, make sense to me, so I marked it as "right" without actually proving it.

Comment: Hi omz.Thank you for the detailed explanation.I have similar problem ,the memory usage is drastically increasing when i keep on rendering the pages and app is crashing after some point of time.I am using separate PDFDocument for each page(contains only one page)that is created and released in drawLayer:inContext: method.please give me a suggestion to avoid this auto caching of page content and reduce the memory usage.

Comment: @Hariprasad I have a slightly the same problem with you. And I can't find any solutions out there. Some say its the framework's bug others is the releasing, but I think mine had released everything. I don't have leaks or anything and still at some point will crash. Have you found a solution for this?