# CGPath leaking after releasing CGPDFDocument

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, memory-leaks, uiscrollview

I'm writing a small PDF viewer for iOS. 
I'm not trying to develop anything complex, just a zoomable `UIScrollView` with 10 PDF pages, leveraging upon `CATiledLayer`.

I think I managed to do everything right, since the viewer works as intended, it's pretty fast and zooms fine.

The only problem I'm noticing is what I think is a small memory leak when I dismiss the PDF viewer controller. I see that when a page is drawn with `CGContextDrawPDFPage`, CoreGraphics is instantiating a lot of `CGPath` with `CGTypeCreateInstance`. When I dismiss the controller, I can see that `CGPDFDocument` and `CGPDFPage` objects are getting correctly deallocated but NOT the `CGPath` objects. They just stay there, as persistent objects and thus slowly saturating my memory.

Do you think that I'm missing something? Or is this an intended behaviour? Or maybe it's just a bug in CoreGraphics?

Thank you

**Edit**: added code markdown

Comment: Are you remembering to `CGPathRelease` on any path that you create? Try running the static analyzer to see if Xcode picks up anything obvious.

Comment: Hi Ian, I'm not creating any `CGPath` , I think they are being created when `CGContextDrawPDFPage` gets called. It is puzzling, since `CGContextDrawPDFPage` , and the corresponding `CGPDFPage`, gets deallocated correctly

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say `CGPDFDocumentRef` instead of `CGContextDrawPDFPage` :-)

Comment: I've exactly the same issue, and cannot find out what is the problem. Here is another similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668772/what-tf-are-the-secrets-behind-pdf-memory-allocation-cgpdfdocumentref. The fact is this is causing crashes on old devices... This is really annoying :/ Might indeed come from a bug of CoreGraphics